# How send an email with Arabic from velocity template

Tags: java, spring, email, velocity

I used UTF-8 as character encoding. but still did get the proper output.

```
message.setSubject(emailSubject,"UTF-16");

message.setSubject(emailSubject,"UTF-8");
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(emailBody, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

[EMail content is looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc8et.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you get "?" there are 2 options.

1. Information is intact but the client that displays the info doesn't know how to properly display the info.
2. The information actually got corrupted/lost.

What helped me a lot when I diagnosed such issues was to convert the information into unicode sequences and than you can clearly see if your info is valid or corrupted
There is an Open Source java library MgntUtils written and maintained by me that has a Utility that converts Strings to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

Except using it to diagnose the issue you can just take your text and convert it to unicode sequences and send that instead of text. in this case you don't have any conversions and the symbols should be displayed correctly by any system. The drawback is that the information size is larger then original text